# `np.add.at` to 2-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for 2-dimensional version of `np.add.at()`.

The expected behavior is as follows.

```
augend = np.zeros((10, 10))
indices_for_dim0 = np.array([1, 5, 2])
indices_for_dim1 = np.array([5, 3, 1])
addend = np.array([1, 2, 3])

### some procedure substituting np.add.at ###

assert augend[1, 5] == 1
assert augend[5, 3] == 2
assert augend[2, 1] == 3
```

Any advice will help!

Comment: In your example there are no repeated indices.  Is that always the case?

Comment: No, it is not. There can be a repeated indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) multidimensionally as it is. The `indices` argument contains the following in the description:

> ... If first operand has multiple dimensions, indices can be a tuple of array like index objects or slice

So:

```
augend = np.zeros((10, 10))
indices_for_dim0 = np.array([1, 5, 2])
indices_for_dim1 = np.array([5, 3, 1])
addend = np.array([1, 2, 3])
np.add.at(augend, (indices_for_dim0, indices_for_dim1), addend)
```

More simply:

```
augend[indices_for_dim0, indices_for_dim1] += addend
```

If you're really worried about the multidimensional aspect and your augend is a vanilla contiguous C order array, you can use [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and [`ravel_multi_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html) to perform the operation on a 1D view:

```
indices = np.ravel_multi_index((indices_for_dim0, indices_for_dim1), augend.shape)
raveled = augend.ravel()
np.add.at(raveled, indices, addend)
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. The first answer is the one I was looking for. I also tried to the second one (i.e. augend[indices_for_dim0, indices_for_dim1] += addend), but this yielded unexpected result if the indices have overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner:

```
np.add.at(augend, (indices_for_dim0, indices_for_dim1), addend)
augend
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

assert augend[1, 5] == 1
assert augend[5, 3] == 2
assert augend[2, 1] == 3
# No AssertionError
```

When using 2d-array for `np.add.at`, `indices` must be of a tuple where `tuple[0]` contains all the first coordinates and `tuple[1]` contains all the second coordinates.

Comment: Thanks very much! this was the very answer I was looking for!